# how to use multiple columns values to calculate the result in pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

```
def WA(A,B):
    c = A*B
    return c.sum()/A.sum()
    
sample = pd.pivot_table(intime,index=['year'], columns = 'DV', values = ['A','B'],
                        aggfunc={'A' : [len,np.sum], 'B' : [WA]}, fill_value = 0)
```

I'm grouping the dataframe by year and wanted to find the weighted avg of column B
I'm supposed to multiple column A with B then sum up the result and divide it by the sum of A [functian WA() does that]

I really have no idea on how to call the function by passing both the values